# Rails:Email validation in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am importing excel sheet containing(name,date of birth,email) and validating email in model  with the below code

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[a-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,4})$/, :message => "Invalid email ID"
```

Now I have to show people having invalid email format.Is it possible to validate with this or any another way....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this  i got the person name whose email is not valid

```
  if @person.save

 else
    @err << {:name => ..............,:error => @person.errors.messages}
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

Go through http://my.rails-royce.org/2010/07/21/email-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-without-regexp/ It really helps you.

Comment: The link is now down, so have a look at [this page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise) from the Devise gem, which shows the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd humbly recommend against attempting to validate email formats due to the wide number of combinations and formats that make up a valid email address.

If, however, you wish to persue this path then the full RegEx can be seen [here](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

HTH